# How to get first day of current month?

Tags: python, datetime

I am writing a script for my project where I need to add start date and end date in online webpage. Start date must be current month's first date and end date must be yesterday's date.

Below is the code for predefined days. Kindly help to solve. In below I have to add manually from yesterday to require days, but need auto find to put first day of current month.

```
daystostart = 6
daystoend = 1

# Time and Date

yesterday = dt.datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(days=daystostart)
StartDT = yesterday.strftime("%Y-%m-%d ") + "00:00:00"

yesterdayNightEnd = dt.datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(days=daystoend)
EndDT = yesterdayNightEnd.strftime("%Y-%m-%d ") + "23:59:59"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime

today = datetime.today().date()
first_day = today.replace(day=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

first day of current month

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
now = dt.now()

dt(now.year, now.month, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime
today = datetime.today()
first_day = datetime(today.year,today.month,1)
#2021-08-01 00:00:00
```