# Setting the FirstDay in TableCalendar to the First day of the current month in Dart Flutter Project

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to set the firstDay in the calendar in TableCalendar to be the first day of the current month. I am not sure how to set it.

Here is how it is formated now:

```
                      TableCalendar(
                        firstDay: DateTime.utc(2022, 11, 01),
                        lastDay: DateTime.utc(2022, 11, 30),
                        focusedDay: DateTime.now(),
                      ),
```

Question how to set the firstDay to the first day of the current month?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get first day of current month?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68686884/how-to-get-first-day-of-current-month)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var date = DateTime.now();

TableCalendar(
    firstDay: DateTime.utc(date.year, date.month, 1),
    lastDay: DateTime.utc(date.year, date.month + 1, 0),
    currentDay: DateTime.utc(date.year, date.month, 1),
    focusedDay: DateTime.utc(date.year, date.month, 1),
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

according to me the easiest way is to get the last day of date,

```
lastday = DateTime(date.year, date.month + 1, 0);
```

this will return last day in '2022-11-30 00:00:00.000' and than u can fetch day as integer if u want only day as integer

``
lastday=DateTime(now.year,now.month+1,0).day